# SQL Columns Grouping

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an SQL View Name dbo.financialactuals

```
ACCTNAME     Month    Balance  Acctctgry  Year  Description
sales           1     344.78   income    2018   revenueAX
sales           2     2744.78  income    2018   ProduceAX
sales           3     8745.78  income    2018   annualAx
INTEREST INC    1      7866     Interest  2018   ProduceAX
INTEREST INC    2      766      Interest  2018   CTGAX3
sales           5     744.78    other     2018   AX
```

I tried to sum balance by AcctName But it still showing the same result. I think it's because of the description column. So, I removed the description from the select statement but it's acting same.

```
       SELECT AcctName,
       SUM(Balance) AS Balance,
       AcctCtrgry,
       Year, 
       FROM dbo.financialactuals
       GROUP BY AcctName, Acctctrgy, Year,
```

I need an output like this.

```
           AcctNAme        Balance        AcctCtrgy             Year       
           sales           -3089.56          income             2018
         INTEREST INC       9632           InterestINC          2018
```

Comment: What happened to the last row `sales, other`? Is it included somewhere? Also, the numbers in your example don't add up.

Comment: Barring some syntax issues (extra commas, `dbo.dbo.financialactuals`), this seems fine. If this is querying a view and not a table, there might be some oddball logic going on "under the hood" that is affecting the results. Review that, and possibly post it?

Comment: I do not understand your arithmetic.  Please explain how exactly you came up with your sales balance value.

Comment: Not to mention the SQL in in the OP is not actually valid syntax.  There is definitely something missing here as if you cleaned up the SQL above it would actually give the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said already in the comments this should give the requested result.

```
 SELECT AcctName,
   SUM(Balance) AS Balance,
   AcctCtrgry,
   Year, 
   FROM dbo.financialactuals
   GROUP BY AcctName, Acctctrgy, Year
```

But the sum on the sales will be -11835.34 not -3089.56.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: It's repeating the acctnames

Comment: It's not summing

Comment: Are you sure that you don't include 'Description' in your group list?

Comment: yes. I'm trying to sum by account name. Still those account names are repeating. Don't know why?

Comment: Can you please edit the question and show what is your ACTUAL response?

Comment: An double check that the line with group by is only that:
"GROUP BY AcctName, Acctctrgy, Year"